# Gett access to method in React

Tags: reactjs

I have still onclick on button Form.js:232 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeTrash' of null

```
  removeTrash(index) {
        console.log('remove', index);
    }



    <tbody>
                                    {this.state.trashArray.map(function (data, index) {
                                        return <tr>
                                            <th scope="row" key={data.key}>{index + 1}</th>
                                            <td>{data.odpad}</td>
                                            <td>{data.waga}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button type="button" value="add" className="btn btn-danger btn-remove"
                                                        onClick={function (data, index) {
                                                            console.log(data);
                                                            this.removeTrash(index);
                                                        }}>X
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>;
                                    })
                                    }
                                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(data);
this.removeTrash(index);
```

here `this` is referencing to the function that contains it and not the class!

to solve this, before return the  `<tbody> ...</tbody>`  add this line replace this by that,

`let that = this`

and then

```
that.removeTrash(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a binding issue, u need to bind `onClick` method. Try any on of this:

```
<button type="button" value="add" className="btn btn-danger btn-remove"
        onClick={()=>{this.removeTrash(index)}}
</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" value="add" className="btn btn-danger btn-remove"
     onClick={this.removeTrash.bind(this,index)}
</button>
```

And use this part:

```
{this.state.trashArray.map((data, index)=> {
    return 
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" key={data.key}>{index + 1}</th>
            <td>{data.odpad}</td>
            <td>{data.waga}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" value="add" className="btn btn-danger btn-remove"
                        onClick={this.removeTrash.bind(this, index)}>
                    X
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>;
    })
}
```

Comment: No in You option for ES6  Form.js:234 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeTrash' of undefined   And in option for ES7   I have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeTrash' of undefined same only option with let that = this working but i cant pass index

Comment: check the updated ans, let me know if it is not working.